# Laravel 5 custom "Not Found" page

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing, middleware

The question is the following.

How can I set default route for non-existed pages in Laravel 5? So when page not found, than some default view is shown with status 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for non-existing pages you should use status code 404 but if you wants to pass `200 ok` then this should work fine.

create a file `404.blade.php` at `views >> errors` directory and place `abort(200);` in it.

**Update**
Or you can place this code in file `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{

    // 404 page with status code 200
    if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        return response()->view('errors.404', [], 200);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);

}
```

Note: creating a file `404.blade.php` at `views >> errors` directory is must OR pass another custom view.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom 404 view by creating a Blade template called **404.blade.php** and placing it in the **resources/views/errors** directory.

However, do *not* send a 200 OK HTTP status. That just breaks everything the HTTP protocol stands for.

Comment: Sometimes we need non-standard solutions.

Comment: @KenShiro Not when it defies HTTP conventions. Why would you want to send a 200 OK response if the page was not found?

Comment: We need to show always the single page, no matter what user is requested. And sometimes we add custom pages for some special requests.

Comment: @KenShiro You can still show the same view, but send a different HTTP status. The view—or anything about your app architecture—should _not_ dictate what HTTP status code is returned. If the user doesn’t exist, send a 404. You can still have a pretty view.